# bash script: how to cd when uncertain of whole directory name?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash script to install the latest texlive on a server (part of provisioning in Vagrant). Texlive comes packaged as `install-tl-unx.tar.gz`, but when unpacked, the resulting directory name includes the date of the last upgrade, e.g. `install-tl-20161129`. Since I can't predict the date portion of the directory name, how can I `cd` into it? Is there a script equivalent of hitting tab? I searched but couldn't find anything applicable.

Comment: You may use `tar` to extract the name of the directory and use then use it at your convenience...

Comment: Can someone tell me why this question got downvoted? I strive to search hard before asking, and then make my questions as clear as possible. I got the answer to my question promptly - Cyrus had no trouble understanding what I was asking.

Comment: Anonymity has weird effects...

Comment: Yup, I guess they want to stay anonymous (after I asked, either they changed their mind or someone else upvoted it back to 0). Many of my questions are too unique to my situation to be of general interest, but I thought this one might be more helpful to the masses. So I was surprised when I saw -1 and thought I should learn what I'm doing wrong so I can become a better community member.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest to use globbing:

```
cd install-tl-*
```

or to catch 8 digits with globbing:

```
cd install-tl-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
```

Comment: "globbing" - I would have never guessed that term, and had no idea I could use `*` in such a case, but indeed, that works great!

Comment: Or, if you are a gambler, you can play with `shopt -o cdspell`